# Where can i find the source code of TextView.setText(..) method?

Tags: android, textview, android-source

I am displaying Arabic text on TextView with custom fonts. But the small character called "Araab" are not getting positioned well. They overlap on other characters..

I have posted a query:
[How to ajust Arabic 'aarab' characters? Please see my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256149/how-to-ajust-arabic-aarab-characters-please-see-my-code)

but not getting any help. **I think if i could find the source code for TextView.setText() method i can over-ride it in my project and debug it..??**

Please help me where can i find the source code for it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is source code url for android http://source.android.com/source/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Android source is open source, either find from there:
http://source.android.com/

or TextView class:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Answer (score 1):

The official Android sources can be found as part of the Android Open Source Project (AOSP), and the source for the TextView class in particular, can be found at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java.

(this URL works at least in Feb 2021)